# Windows-7 system files integrity

Tags: windows-7, windows, security, filesystems, rootkit

Is there a tool that will check integrity of system files in Win7 and search for invalid or changed ones. I would like to find which files were changed by rootkit installed on system. It would be nice if there existed some databases with system files names and corresponding hashes (original and updated by Windows Update).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `sfc /scannow` command.

This command (System File Checker) scans the integrity of all protected Windows 7 system files and replaces incorrect corrupted, changed, or damaged versions with the correct versions if possible.

You can read this tutorial on how to use it:

[How to Repair Windows 7 System Files with System File Checker](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html)

Comment: I already tried sfc /verifyonly and everything was OK. But i guess there is some change in system files because i have some rootkit installed, and to modify my view on file system it should change some system files?

Comment: For every anti-virus measure, there's a virus to beat it (was that Sun Tsu?)

Comment: some rootkits are installed in user's folder - search under Users for .exe and .dll if any they shouldn't be there. Also check with something like HijackThis to see what is loading during the boot

Comment: Although this did not fix my problem it seams like good tool to check system integrity. Thx!